# Sed - strict matching

Tags: bash, sed, matching

I want my sed to delete only what I give him.

For exemple, I have this

```
sed -ie "/$1/d" /etc/asterisk/voicemail.conf &>/dev/null
```

In the case where my voicemail.conf has some strings like "hello" and "helloc", if my $1 is "hello" that will also remove the line that contains "helloc"

Comment: Just be careful that your variable doesn't contain any special characters: `[`, `]`, `*`, `\ `, `.`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `\b` that corresponds to the limit of a word :

```
sed -ie "/\b$1\b/d" /etc/asterisk/voicemail.conf &>/dev/null
```

Comment: To match the full line, `"/^$1\$/d"`